# Multiple selectmenu one datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, select-menu

Looking for a jQuery based selectmenu, which uses a central datasource so I don't have to include the country options 500 times on the page, just once. Does anything handy like this exists in the wild?

Comment: country options? what are you on about? what do you want in your select menu?

Comment: one way would be jquery ui autocomplete

Comment: There are a lot of countries in this very world :). So, when a result set comes back on the site, lets say with 200 rows, you have to show a selectmenu for each row, and for each selectmenu, you have to include the same group of options again and again. That's what I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take a few guesses here...

You have a number of <SELECT> items on your page. 500, it would seem. And they are all for selecting a country.  And instead of having

```
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
```

etc 500 times you want to get that list once from a server. Via an AJAX call?

Bad idea. Why? Your page will no longer work without Javascript. If that's not a problem, read on...

If you write the server-side request to return a whole bunch of <option> tags then you call that (with $.get or $.ajax) and store in a javascript variable. Then loop over the select tags you want to fiddle and use .innerHTML to add them.

I don't think you'll find anything ready-to-go on the internet that does exactly what you want because its pretty trivial and would require customising for your particular server - PHP, Django, whatever - and your particular HTML (you might not want to frob all the select widgets).